# Firebase: Not finding user when logging in

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I try to log in to my app it crashes and tells me

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on this line of code

`let user = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid`

I have "autologin" in `AppDelegate`:

```
[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        //Send previously logged in users to main menu, or send to signIn screen
        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
            if let user = user {
                // Take user to a home page
                let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let homePage = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! CustomTabBarController
                self.window?.rootViewController = homePage
            } else {
                // Take user to sign In View Controller
                let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let signIn = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewController") as! SignInViewController
                self.window?.rootViewController = signIn
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

The strange thing is when I sign up a new user, I can log in with that user after signing up, but if I log out again, it crashes when signing in.

**EDIT***
Here is how the user es logged in:

```
 @IBAction func logInButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if (emailTextField.text?.isEmpty)!{
            errorMsg(title: "Error", message: "Missing Email")
        }
        if (passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)! {
            errorMsg(title: "Error", message: "Missing password")
        }
        else
        {
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in
                if user != nil {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToMenuFromLoginSegue", sender: self)

                }
                else {
                    if let myError = error?.localizedDescription {
                        print(myError)
                    }

                }
                //Diplay errormsg for loginErrors
                if error != nil {
                    if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {

                        switch errCode {
                        case .invalidEmail:
                            self.errorMsg(title: "Feil", message: "Invalid Email")
                        case .wrongPassword:
                            self.errorMsg(title: "Error", message: "Wrong password")
                        case .userNotFound:
                            self.errorMsg(title: "Error", message: "No user registered with that username")
                        case .networkError:
                            self.errorMsg(title: "Error", message: "Please check connection")
                        default:
                            print("Create User Error: \(error!)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: As you are `force unwrapping` the `currentuser` which seems to be `nil` so that crash is happening. No exp. with `Firebase` but i think the above code will not autologin the user as its just listening the state event. It will be better if you can share more code on how you are invoking autologin and on what point you are using this line `let user = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the segue is connected directly to the `logInButton` in Storyboard. If so, the segue will perform without any authentication.